# Is the six-month rule a hard rule or a guideline?

Tags: usa, passports, italian-citizens

I'm an Italian citizen and got my ESTA last year that's still valid until my passport expiration in 2023.
Italy is also in the 6 months club so it shouldn't be a problem.

I will travel to the United States, in May but my passport will expire in August. My only concern is: **Is the 6-month cutoff a general rule or could the border agent let me in anyway?**

Comment: Clearly the agent has the last word but why should him make an exception for you?

Comment: good point, but you never know :)

Comment: There's time to renew your passport before May. Why would you want to risk it?

Comment: Do you have an Italian passport? As you said, Italy is in the six-month club, so why should the passport validity be a problem (assuming you are leaving before your passport expiry and have a ticket for it)?

Comment: @xngtng because I sometimes read about CBP officers that, even if everything is perfectly fine, love to find problems. So since my case would be one of those, I have some doubts about it... I guess I will renew my passport and ask for a new ESTA

Comment: @Val it may be prudent to renew your passport but it is hardly necessary.  As long as you enter more than 90 days before your passport expires, your period of admission will not be shortened.

Comment: @phoog I will stay 2 weeks, so not a big deal

Comment: @Val Sure, but this applies regardless of the validity left on your passport... Unfortunately, if you meet one officer in a bad mood, they can try find problems everywhere.

Comment: @xngtng yes sure. that's why I asked. I don't have many doubts now :) I will ask for a new passport and that's it

Answer (score 12):

Your question as written doesn't make a lot of sense.

As you've stated, Italy is on the list of countries that do NOT require an additional 6 months passport validity when entering the US.  This list, which is commonly known as the '6 months club' is documented in the US Department of State regulations as '[9 FAM 403.9-3(B)(2)](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html)' which means that it's an official rule, and thus not something generally open to interpretation.

Thus as an Italian citizen you will be allowed entry to the US even if your passport does not have 6 months validity beyond the expected end of your stay.  Note that if your passport has less than 90 days validity then your entry to the US will also likely expire at the same time as your passport (ie, you may not get the full 90 days that someone entering on ESTA would normally receive).

If your request was more generic, such as for a country that is NOT in the '6 months club', then the answer is likely "it depends".  Immigration staff do have some ability to override requirements like this under specific circumstances, however it extremely unlikely that you'd even get the chance to present your case - checking passport and visa requirements is generally carried out by airline staff (and/or automatically by various systems on check-in), so if you didn't meet such a requirement then it's highly likely you would be denied boarding and not allowed to actually travel to the US.

Comment: Your mileage may vary. I had an extremely unpleasant discussion with CBP officer because he claimed "there wasn't enough time left" on our documents. Our documents were all perfectly fine and well within the legal requirements.  Apparently the CBP officer just was bored and needed someone to torture.

Comment: @Hilmar thanks for reporting your experience, this is exactly what I'm afraid of

Comment: @Hilmar Are you not a US citizen?

Comment: I wasn't at the time.

Comment: @Val: there really isn't a whole lot you can do about it. If the officer is in a fool mood you just have to grin and bear it. It's most just blustering. They do bark a lot but they rarely bite.

Comment: "Note that if your passport has less than 90 days validity then your entry to the US will also likely expire at the same time as your passport (ie, you may not get the full 90 days that someone entering on ESTA would normally receive)": the hedging is unnecessary; you can delete "likely" and change "may" to "will."  US law does not allow visitors (with B visas or under the VWP) to be admitted beyond the validity of their passport.  Six-month-club visitors may be admitted until the expiration of the passport, while others may be admitted until six months before the passport expires.

Comment: "Italy is on the list of countries that do NOT require" -- should that be the other way around? That the _US_ does not require the plus six months password validity for holders of Italian passports?